# "Indeed/in deed/indid/in did"

Tags: orthography

I am not a native speaker and get constantly confused which one to use when I would like to approve some statement or someone's sentence.

> A really nice one **indeed**.
>     A really nice one **in deed**.
>     A really nice one **indid**.
>     A really nice one **in did**.

I guess the first one is correct, but others may be correct in some other contexts. When do we use each of these?

Comment: Just a note: the word *deed* and the word *did* have different vowel sounds. If you're a non-native speaker you may have trouble telling them apart.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no such thing as *in did* or *indid*. Use *indeed* to mean *really* and *in deed* to mean *in action*. For example,

> She is beautiful **indeed**

means she is truly beautiful, while

> She is beautiful **in deed**

means her actions are beautiful.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing this up for me. I will now know that all I can use is the *double e word* because it's the only one that is correct in those cases where I get confused. :) It would be much more complicated when many possible forms could be used...

Comment: Actually, indeed comes from a shortening of 'in deed'. This was when 'in deed' was similar in usage to 'in fact'. Over time, the meaning of deed has evolved I guess, hence the difference.

Comment: As a point about common modern usage, 'indeed' as one word is very often (although not exclusively) used to confirm something that's already been said or to put emphasis on an answer to a question. For example, if someone asked "Isn't she beautiful?", the response "She is beautiful indeed." would make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

*Indeed* is spelt as one word. Your third and fourth examples have no meaning.